# how can I use WP_Query to exclude a specific tag.?

Tags: tags, exclude

I have the following working code for a query on a specific category and tag slug:

```
$args = array(
'category_name' => $cat_name,
'tag' => $tag_name,
'post__not_in' => $sticky
 );

 $my_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

I can't figure out how to exclude a specific tag name from the query. Do I need the tag ID? How do I get it? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I would note that the performances of searches such as `post__not_in` don't scale very well on larger sites

Answer (score 6):

Use `tag__not_in` parameter. You have to use tag ID for this parameter

```
$args = array(
    'category_name' => $cat_name,
    'tag' => $tag_name,
    'post__not_in' => $sticky,
    'tag__not_in' => array($tag_id_1, $tag_id_2)
);

$my_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use 'tag__not_in' and you need the ID of the Tag. Have a look into https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by to retrieve the term object, where the ID is contained.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I don't understand how to get the tag ID from this function:

Comment: $tag = get_term_by('name', 'my-sticky', 'post_tag');
    echo 'the term id is '. $tag;

Comment: echo 'the term id is ' . (int) $tag->term_id;

Comment: I'm getting a term_id of 0. Could this possibly be correct? How can I tell?